# Javafx - Security concern while deploying App using Fxlauncher vs Java Web Start

Tags: javafx, java-web-start, tornadofx

I have created a Tornadofx application and was looking to deploy it in production. For this I was considering two options:

1. Fxlauncher
2. Java web start

Fxlauncher seemed pretty easy to use and deploy with only gradle configurations and commands.
**But my main concern is whether it is secure enough?**
For example, In Java web start, I was reading through the documentations and found this :

> Signing JAR Files Used in Java Web Start
>   Java Web Start enforces a security sandbox. By default it grants any application, including application clients, only minimal privileges. Because Java Web Start applications can be so easily downloaded, Java Web Start provides protection from potentially harmful programs that might be accessible over the network. If an application requires a higher privilege level than the sandbox permits, the code that needs privileges must be in a JAR file that was signed. When Java Web Start downloads such a signed JAR file, it displays information about the certificate that was used to sign the JAR, and it asks you whether you want to trust that signed code. If you agree, the code receives elevated permissions and runs. If you reject the signed code, Java Web Start does not start the downloaded application.

Basically, signing of jars is one of the key concerns while using Java web start and JNLP ; But with Fxlauncher, I was not able to find any such requirement or standard to do so.
So how does Fxlauncher handle such security issues?
Currently, using the fxlauncher, I am able to read/write files from/to my client's machine. Is this ok without jar signing ?

FYI, I haven't practically used Java web start, was just reading through Oracle guidelines.
Refrences:

[Signing JAR Files Used in Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3659/gcjlg/index.html)

[Understanding Signing and Verification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html)

Comment: Usually the concern with this kind of stuff isn't your concern as a developer, as you aren't developing a malicious app.  It is a concern of the users of the app.  Specifically, does the user choose to allow Java applications to be run via web start? and, if they do, what applications do they trust? and, are they confident that somebody won't trick them into running a malicious application either through an exploit or social engineering?  If they are OK with all that, they are probably OK with running your app if they trust you.

Comment: From your point of view when you ask "is it secure enough?", what in particular are you you worried about?  What attack vectors or malicious action could occur which violate your security tolerance level and would constitute harm?  What would the cost of that harm be and what effort do you want to spend to mitigate it?  Asking questions like these can help you decide an appropriate security strategy for your app and providing the questions and answers you came up with can help others advise you on the app security on forums such as this or https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @jewelsea I am worried about scenarios where say I deploy my app on a public server..If Somehow a hacker manages to catch hold of my app jar, replaces it with his own, now how would my client know whether the application he will run is the one which I have developed. That is why we sign the jars with our certificate which the hacker would not have.

Answer (score 2):

FXLauncher ultimately creates an installable native application using the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javapackager.html) utility. You could say that security concerns are moved up one level from the JVM to the OS, if you will. Hence, you should treat an application packaged with FXLauncher the same way you would treat any other native application.

The Gradle plugin currently doesn't expose the ability to sign your application bundle, but you could do that separately until the plugin catches up. Signing the application gives your end users confidence that you are who you say you are and improves the installation experience by replacing the security warning with a dialog that presents your identity instead.

Bottom line: When you install any native application you are basically at the mercy of the developer to some extent, and this is just as much true for FXLauncher packaged applications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What if I go with the way of exposing jar itself and not a native installer; in that case, is it possible to use Fxlauncher in coordination with the JNLP providing the jar signing feature? If yes, can you give me a brief on how to implement it?

Comment: No, that's not currently possible, but I'll look into it for the 2.0 reboot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the JNLP / WebStart command to launch your signed application.  You'll need to sign any libraries with the same certificate or cordon them off into separate .jnlp files.

As far as a native install experience, take the signed and sandboxed WebStart app here:

```
https://www.bekwam.net/sortme/sortme.jnlp
```

Since the WebStart plugin doesn't allow you to pull up the apps directly anymore, you can capture a native running experience by doing something like this.

```
$ alias sortme='javaws https://www.bekwam.net/sortme/sortme.jnlp'
```

This allows you to type "sortme" from a command line and run the app.  If you want to go further, you can do add a file called sortme.desktop (for Ubuntu).  This lets you double-click on an icon or access this from the launcher.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sort Me
Exec=/opt/jdk1.8.0_141/bin/javaws https://www.bekwam.net/sortme/sortme.jnlp
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-BAMFGenerated=true
```

This deployment lets you take advantage of a content delivery network (CDN) to serve up your JNLP and JAR files from a super-fast download server.  You provide in your install scripts the "last mile".  You'll get all the assurance of a signed app and even a sandboxed version if it's feasible.

Comment: Hi. So my question was whether Fxlauncher does provide any sort of signing jar security; Your answer describes how one uses javaws and can get a native install experience .. which is right. So basically you are supporting java web start way of deploying my app rather than going the Fxlauncher way. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

There
is definitely a security concern.

You can use my spinoff framework [update4j](https://github.com/update4j/update4j), very similar to fxlauncher but way superior. It has a signature verification feature.